# How can i make a control to take whole space of parent in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I want to take a text box to take the whole space of a gridpane but I don't want to hardcode the size. I am swt programmer where I used to pass `swt.fill,swt.fill` to take the vertical and horizontal space. And upon resizing the window the textbox used to expand vertically and horizontally. Can I achieve this using javafx. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you have to set, the row span and the column span. for example if you have 4 column in your gridpane and you want a textfield who have the size of the 4 column you need to set the column span to REMAINING. And your field will take all the column

[column span](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setColumnSpan%28javafx.scene.Node,%20java.lang.Integer%29)